# Firebase rewrite - Allow dots in url parameters

Tags: firebase-hosting

How should the rewrite rule be in order to allow dots in URL parameters.

For example I have an URL like this:
http://example.com/path?param=abc.def

This will result a 404 page. Current rule is:

```
"rewrites": [{
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
}
```

Comment: Can you list the config of what is not working? Is it the same domain?

Comment: @talves: Yes, it's the same domain. There's no config, I just want to add a token to the URL params (http://example.com/?token=XXX, where XXX may contain dots). I'm using Firebase hosting.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Not sure how to fix it yet. If there is a dot on the URL I get 404 and not redirection to the index.html file